# Does Visual C++ 2015 support constexpr lambdas?

Tags: visual-c++

It seems not but just wanted to check I'm not getting the syntax wrong:

```
int x = []() constexpr {return 1; }();
```

`error C3260: 'type': skipping unexpected token(s) before lambda body`

Comment: `constexpr` lambdas are a C++17 feature, and are not expected to be supported by comformant compilers yet. I think the current VC++ does not even support C++14 lambdas yet, I've only heard of its support on Twitter recently, so it's probably for the next update or VS"15"

Comment: You can create a source file that sports one and then, like, see whether it compiles.